# Exception when serializing a stateless object with jackson Json

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have been using the jackson implementation of the json protocol in my own little project, and it has gone just fine a while now until I decided (for the first time) to serialize a stateless object.

I know that might sound weird, why would I want to send a stateless object? What I serialize is requests for a server, and this particular one conatins no fields, just code for an instruction on the server side. My model can take any ClientRequest implementation and call it's perform() method. I want it to work even though the request comes without fields.

Code looks like this:

```
public class GetWallInputsRequest implements ClientRequest<List<WallInput>>
{
   @JsonCreator public GetWallInputsRequest()
   {
   }

   @Override public ServerResponse<List<WallInput>> perform()
   {
      return new WallMessageResponse( Wall.WALL.getInputs() );
   }
}
```

I get JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class GetWallInputsRequest.
Google does not help me, which makes me wonder if I'm just being stupid. Sadly I don't see a way out of this.

I solved it after a lot of brute force attempting different things. And by solved it I mean not figured it out but made it work. By adding the line:

```
@JsonAutoDetect(getterVisibility=JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
```

above the class declaration it seems to work out. Why this is necessary I don't know, but now It sends an empty json string instead of crashing.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  If you have solved your question, we appreciate that you post the solution as an answer, then accept your own answer.  This prevents your question from appearing in the unanswered questions list.

Comment: @Bystam -- Do you have a question?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says

> Value that indicates that no access modifiers are auto-detectable: this can be used to explicitly disable auto-detection for specified types.

Since your class doesn't include any explicit notations to tell Jackson that there's a field or method to serialize, it determines that there is indeed nothing to look for. Without this, I presume, it's going to expect *something*, as suggested in the documentation quoted.

http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.0/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.html